# MongoDB error "not authorised on admin"

Tags: mongodb

I know this is a very common question for MongoDB, but I really tried most of the answers, but could not solve this issue. 
So I feel I'm missing something Somewhere

Here are the steps:

1. Downloaded latest version 3.03 of MongoDB.
2. Custom installed to f:\MEAN\MongoDB.
3. F:\MEAN>sc.exe create MongoDBSvc binPath= "\"F:\mean\mongodb

\bin\mongod.exe\" -- service --config=\"F:\MEAN\MongoDBData\log\1.cfg\"" 
DisplayName= "MongoDBSvc" start= "auto"
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

`F:\MEAN>net start MongoDbSvc`

The MongoDBSvc service is starting.
The MongoDBSvc service was started successfully.

`F:\MEAN>mongo`

MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3 connecting to: test

```
  > view dbs
   2015-05-28T14:00:10.907+1000 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected      identifier
 > show dbs
    2015-05-28T14:00:21.886+1000 E QUERY    Error: listDatabases failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command {  listDatabases:
     1.0 }",
           "code" : 13
   }
       at Error (<anonymous>)
       at Mongo.getDBs (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47:15)
       at shellHelper.show (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:630:33)
       at shellHelper (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:524:36)
       at (shellhelp2):1:1 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47
     > ^C
          bye
```

Comment: It would be helpful to tell us what you tried already. If you tried most of the answers, why didn't you give the remaining answers a try?
Am I right that you have authentication enabled?

Comment: To me it looks like the dbAdmin has no right to list Databases: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbAdmin . See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23945653/1377224

Comment: I'm new to MongoDB and just want to get started so that I can try learn more, I'm not sure if Authentication is enabled and how to do it. and this issue is holding me back. I cant even see the list of database leave alone creating collections and insert data.

Comment: Please add to your question the content of F:\MEAN\MongoDBData\log\1.cfg . And btw, putting your config in log folder might not be the best decision.

Comment: I tried same settings/ config on my laptop with win7 and every thing worked for me on very first attempt. By the way I'm sorry that I've mentioned before that I'm trying to install on Win 8.1.

Comment: Well, I've no idea then. Maybe you should try to ask directly mongodb for support about it.