# Can not access MongoDb collections on Compose.io with Mongo Client

Tags: mongodb, compose-db

Since last week I can not access my mongoDb collections on Compose.io using any mongo client. Client log says it is connected to DB but when I want to list collections or view document says "Collection not found!". I till can connect with terminal and do there whatever I need.

Initially I thought it is a problem  with my MacOS machine, but then I tried to connect from other computers and using different clients ( Mongo-Express, MongoHub ) still no luck.

Wondering if I'm experiencing this problem alone or other compose.io clients also do ?

- Tried to grant readWrite role to my mongo user as advised here ([MongoDB - admin user not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943651/mongodb-admin-user-not-authorized)), this does not help either.
- Contacted compose.io support, but they swear that did change anything.

Any advise appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to connect to slave node which fails with `{ [MongoError: not master and slaveOk=false] name: 'MongoError' }`
. Connecting with MongoClient to primary node solves the problem.

Comment: and how do you connect to a primary node?