# Executing some query on MLab generate not auth error

Tags: mongodb, heroku, gridfs

I would like to move the local implementations (mongoDB gridFS content repository)  to cloud Heroku using mLAB. But I have a problem because some of the functionality of generating below error :

> "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command {
>   listDatabases: 1.0 }",    "code" : 13

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I use user generated in the normal way with a web application with role : dbOwner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - admin user not authorized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943651/mongodb-admin-user-not-authorized)

Comment: The dbOwne role does not have permissions to execute the command "listDatabases" (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/built-in-roles/#dbOwner)