# Application unable to connect to mongodb on DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: node.js, mongodb

From the terminal, the application launches and connects with MongoDB, but when I attempt to access it at the IP address of the droplet (with the correct port), I am getting an error:

`MongoError: not authorized on cmf to execute command`  (`cmf` is the dbname).

I followed the install & setup instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04), creating a user and afterward added the role of `root` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943651/mongodb-admin-user-not-authorized). This was for the admin database.

When logged into the Mongo shell, I can access data thru `db.status()`, and when using admin db I can run `show users` and see the user.

I am confused whether I lack configuration for the `cmf` database. When using `cmf` db, when I run `show users`, nothing is returned.

For unknown reasons, the application cannot connect with mongodb. I am now thoroughly confused about where to go from here.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Could you copy&paste the line of javascript code in which you attempt to connect?

Comment: var url = 'mongodb://localhost/cmf';  mongoose.connect(url);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the database user with password (like in the tutorial included in your question), then upon connecting:

```
var dbHost = 'mongodb://username:password@localhost:port/cmf';
mongoose.connect(dbHost);
```

Where:

- `username` is the username of created user,
- `password` is the password,
- `port` is the correct port of running mongodb (defaults to `27017`).

Comment: Thanks. Getting error: MongoError: Authentication failed..." I replaced the variables in the dbHost string with the user values that display when I run `show users` after `use admin`, and I used 27017 as the port value.  When you say "create the database user" do you mean to create a user (db.createUser) in cmf db instead of admin (admin was used in the setup instructions)?

Comment: Yes, you need an user in `cmf` to connect to `cmf`. To see if it works, in `dbHost` replace `cmf` with `admin` and use it to connect to the `admin`, just for the quick test.

Comment: Progress. It connected!

Comment: SO happy for you!

Comment: Yes, getting closer. Thank you! Now I'm trying to figure out how to add a user for the cmf db.

Comment: First, in your mongo shell: run `use cmf`, then in `cmf` shell run `db.createUser(user)` with the `user` param constructed as here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/

Comment: Success! I created the user in cmf, modified app.js. The app loads and connects with MongoDB, and now displays at the droplet IP address. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me through this!

Comment: Pleasure is mine, I'm happy to be useful :).