# JSON import error MONGOdb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to import a JSON file to MongoDB but getting the below errors

```
VK360@VK360:~$ mongoimport --db cstore --collection stores --drop --file /home/kuliza360/Desktop/Office/Cstoredemo/my_data.json
2018-04-04T10:37:41.545+0530    connected to: localhost
2018-04-04T10:37:41.545+0530    dropping: cstore.stores
2018-04-04T10:37:41.545+0530    Failed: not authorized on cstore to execute command { drop: "stores" }
2018-04-04T10:37:41.545+0530    imported 0 documents
```

I Followed the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943651/mongodb-admin-user-not-authorized) and performed the steps mentioned below in the mongo shell but still have the same error.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
);
exit;
```

**Error after aove execution**

```
2018-04-04T10:33:58.124+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command { createUser: "admin", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ], digestPassword: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 60000.0 } } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1267:15
@(shell):1:1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add --jsonArray before --file

mongoimport --db cstore --collection stores --drop --jsonArray --file /home/kuliza360/Desktop/Office/Cstoredemo/my_data.json

Hopefully this can help other people as well!

Answer (score 0):

Use the query,

mongoimport --db cstore --collection stores --drop --file /home/kuliza360/Desktop/Office/Cstoredemo/my_data.json --username admin --password password

instead of

mongoimport --db cstore --collection stores --drop --file /home/kuliza360/Desktop/Office/Cstoredemo/my_data.json

Comment: 2018-04-04T14:52:40.728+0530 Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
2018-04-04T14:52:40.728+0530 imported 0 documents

Comment: Try this mongoimport --db cstore --collection stores --drop --file /home/kuliza360/Desktop/Office/Cstoredemo/my_data.json --username admin --password password --authenticationDatabase admin

Comment: 2018-04-04T15:18:23.131+0530 Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #0: JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?

Comment: this is because of your json file. can you share it

Comment: [ReportDate "2018-03-08T00:00:00"
ActualSalesPrice 1.59
CSPAccountNo "414693"
DiscountCount 0
Description "TIC TAC GUM WATERMEL"
ZIP "60098"
PromotionAmount 0
POSCode "00980030003"
RefundAmount 0
Totalsales 1.59
TotalCount 1
RefundCount 0
DiscountAmount 0
PromotionCount 0
POSCodeModifier "0 ]

Comment: Above is only a snippet of data

Comment: this doesn't looks like a valid json

Comment: can you send your json file