# I have access to the db but i am Getting some exception while inserting a document into mongodb collection using java

Tags: java, mongodb

Stack trace

> Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command
>   failed with error 13: **'not authorized on mongo_chatbot to execute
>   command { insert: "test", ordered: true, documents:** [ { _id:
>   ObjectId('5b2c9ee1a1b5e20ed53b7237'), name: "pavan", regd: 103, cgpa:
>   "122" } ] }' on server dev-ng-mongo1.phenompeople.com:27017. The full
>   response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on mongo_chatbot
>   to execute command { insert: \"test\", ordered: true, documents: [ {
>   _id: ObjectId('5b2c9ee1a1b5e20ed53b7237'), name: \"pavan\", regd: 103, cgpa: \"122\" } ] }", "code" : 13 }

Comment: Could you please provide us with what you tried, your code, and some more context? We can't help with just a stacktrace.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943651/mongodb-admin-user-not-authorized#29472184?