# MongoDB Compass Community: Databases are visible but their collections are not showing up after authentication

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I created a default admin user with the following command in mongoshell:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "root",
    pwd: "root",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Then I authenticated using the shell and my credentianls as following: 
`mongo --port 27017 -u "root" -p "root" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`

In the shell I am able to see the `users` and `version` collections using:

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
test    0.000GB
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show tables
system.users
system.version
>
```

Now when I try to access these tables from MongoDB Compass Community I first authenticate:
[image]

Now the admin database is showing up empty?

[image]

How can I access the users collection and the other collections from the graphic interface just as I did from the shell?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you cannot see the user collection and other collections is the userAdminAnyDatabase built-in role. By default It does not need the necessary rights to read those collections.
Try root or dbAdminAnyDatabase depends on your needs.

Cheers,

Resource:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

Comment: I am still not able to see any system.collection after setting the role

Answer (score 1):

In short : Use "root" in role instead of "userAdminAnyDatabase" and try again.

---

If use was set this config in "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongod.cfg"

```
security: 
   authorization: enabled
```

You need to comment these 2 line by insert # at start of lines.

Then restart service of "MongoDB Server (MongoDB)".

Open Cmd type these command line by line

```
mongo
use admin
db.grantRolesToUser('admin', [{ role: 'root', db: 'admin' }])
```

Then uncomment security and authorization in mongod.cfg and restart service "MongoDB Server (MongoDB)" again.

You can see how to create or update user role in this answer
Thanks [Dan Dascalescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269037/dan-dascalescu).
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29472184/4418749