# MongoDB - admin unable to become root. "not master"

Tags: mongodb

I created an admin user on a Mongo 4.4 instance (Ubuntu)

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

Then, I tried to `rs.initiate()` and it told me I am not "master". I read this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943651/mongodb-admin-user-not-authorized) where people suggest that I do `db.grantRolesToUser('admin', [{ role: 'root', db: 'admin' }])`, but it doesn't work!

It gives me the following error:

```
uncaught exception: Error: not master :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.grantRolesToUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1613:15
@(shell):1:1
```

Do I have to uninstall MongoDB, reinstall, then create the root user, and then create the admin user?

Comment: Did you configure the service as Replica set?

Comment: I did intend to, but I thought I'd failed. Someone tells me it's a success if it already showing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node can only be "not master" if it's already in a replica set. You can only initiate a replica set once and so you shouldn't be trying to initiate it again, it's already initiated.

Comment: Do you know how to make an admin become "root" or is it useless now?

Comment: When you create a user then it is replicated to the secondary. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I tried to check whether it is replica, but it tells me I'm unauthorized... I know it's probably replica, but isn't it useless if I can't use it? How do I become authorized to use it? Do I have to uninstall?

  `> rs.status()
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetGetStatus: 1.0, lsid: { id: UUID(\"Some ID") }, $db: \"admin\" }", "code" : 13,
"codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}` I asked after doing `db.auth('admin','pwd')`

Comment: To find out the type of a node, issue ismaster to it which doesn't require authentication. See https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#parsing-an-ismaster-response under "parsing ismaster response".